# Finding peak values of graph using ios

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, graph

i have to find the peak values of ECG wave form on ios so for that i have firstly appied the color detection code to detect that black waveform and then i have find the coordinates of that pixels by

```
   CGImageRef imgSource = self.ImageView.image.CGImage;
CFDataRef m_DataRed1 = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imgSource));
CGFloat myheight;
CGFloat mywidth;
myheight= CGImageGetHeight(imgSource);
mywidth = CGImageGetWidth(imgSource);
UInt8 *dataOrignal = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRed1);
double lenghtSource = CFDataGetLength(m_DataRed1);
NSLog(@"lenght : %f",lenghtSource);

int bytesPerPixel_ = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imgSource)/8;
size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imgSource);
NSLog(@"height = %f, width = %f, bytesperPixel = %d",myheight,mywidth,bytesPerPixel_);
for(int x = 0; x < mywidth; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < myheight; y++)
    {
        int pixelStartIndex = 4*((bytesPerRow*x)+y);
        if (pixelStartIndex <= lenghtSource) {
            UInt8 alphaVal = dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex];
            UInt8 redVal = dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex + 1];
            UInt8 greenVal = dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex + 2];
            UInt8 blueVal = dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex + 3];

            if(redVal == 236 || blueVal == 236 || greenVal == 236)
            {
                dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex + 1] = 205;
                dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex +2] = 25;
                dataOrignal[pixelStartIndex+3]= 55;
                NSLog(@"x %d, y = %d, index = %d", x, y,pixelStartIndex);
            }

        }
    }
```

}

```
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imgSource); //202
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imgSource);//173
size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imgSource);
size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imgSource);




NSLog(@"the width = %u and height=%u of the image is ",width,height );
NSLog(@"the bits per component is %zd", bitsPerComponent);
NSLog(@"the bits per pixel is %zd", bitsPerPixel);
NSLog(@"the bytes per row is %zd" , bytesPerRow);

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imgSource);
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imgSource);
CFDataRef newData = CFDataCreate(NULL, dataOrignal, lenghtSource);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(newData);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(newData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo);
CGPoint point = CGContextGetTextPosition(context);
NSInteger xx =  point.x;
```

//    point.y;

```
NSLog(@"this is the value of x axis %d",xx);

CGImageRef newImg = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);





UIImage *newImage1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImg];
self.ImageView.image = newImage1;
```

now i want to find the x and y values of the peak values so can anyone help me that how can i find that ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all define what you want to treat a peak.

If a simple local maximum, then search for a sequence of values a, b, c in neighbouring indices, where a < b > c.
Or even allow equalities, though they can easily detect stationary segments full of peaks.

Probably a better approach to do this search on a smoothed curve.

Comment: thanks for reply you can see this image http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.cvphysiology.com/Arrhythmias/ECG%2520trace%2520with%2520grid.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.cvphysiology.com/Arrhythmias/A009.htm&h=317&w=350&sz=14&tbnid=RVV0Aj8MifiGoM:&tbnh=91&tbnw=100&zoom=1&usg=__ytoheH7aeVESI41K3pCezUBpOjI=&docid=e7Ao78HjT4zcMM&sa=X&ei=sCuIUdy_HaLw4QSU3ICIBw&ved=0CDUQ9QEwAQ&dur=256


from this image you can get idea that what i want to get

Comment: Another approach is to search the peak in the first derivative in the form of positive and then negative sections. You can fine-tune how steep peak you want to accept.

Comment: Yes i know but actully i am not finding how to code and add with the above code can you please do that for me ? i will be very greatfull to you :|

Comment: but right now i am also getting the values of x and y coordinates in the variable also